# Access Apples fall detection on the Series 4

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

Is there a way to get access to Apples fall detection on the Series 4. I would like my watch app to be able to detect when the user falls. I am hoping that Apple would let me get notified when they detect a fall. Is this something that is possible in swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple hasn't made a public API for fall detection. You can file a suggestion with your developer account in Bug Reporter → watchOS + SDK.

Comment: numberOfTimesFallen- Is this the type identifier of healthkit used to detect the fall detection?